# Linq Group By Multiple Columns

Tags: c#, linq

I'm fairly new to linq & having trouble figuring out how to write this.

I have the below collection called animalList

```
AnimalName - MG - Hatch
An1        - 1  -   1
An1        - 1  -   2
An1        - 1  -   3
An2        - 2  -   4
An2        - 2  -   3
```

I need to see each Animal and the count of mg/hatch combinations:

```
AnimalName - Count
An1        - 3
An2        - 2
```

For each animal, I need a distinct count where the MG/Hatch rows have different values.

Here's the query I'm working with but I'm still having issues getting the correct counts.

```
var query = (from a in animalList).ToList()
                         group a by new { a.AnimalName, a.MG,a.Hatch }
                             into grp
                             select new
                             {
                                 grp.Key.AnimalName,
                                 grp.Key.MG,
                                 grp.Key.Hatch,
                                 Quantity = grp.Count()

                             }).ToList();
```

Comment: *I'm still having issues getting the correct counts.* - Elaborate on 'issues'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your query doesn't compile. To make it compile, you would have to change

```
(from a in animalList).ToList()
```

to

```
(from a in animalList
```

Aside from that, you are grouping the animals by *all* the properties (`group a by new { a.AnimalName, a.MG,a.Hatch }`). This will give you a group for each different combination of `AnimalName`, `MG` and `Hatch`. In your case there are no animals with the same name, hatch and MG, so all entries in the list will get their own group, which will result in `grp.Count()` returning 1.

If I understand you correctly, you can solve this with a nested query.

Something like this:

```
var query = from animal in animalList
            group animal by animal.AnimalName into grp
            select new 
            {
               AnimalName = grp.Key,
               Quantity = (from an in grp
                           group an by new { an.Hatch, an.MG } into combinations
                           select combinations).Count()
           };
```

The outer query groups the animals by name and the inner query finds the different combinations for `Hatch` and `MG`.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help and detail of your answer.